# Copy git repository to production from bitbuckets

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm learning Git and implementing it across all my projects.  I've successfully installed Git on my local machine, created git repo's for each project, and started pushing all the commits to my bitbucket account for each project.

Now, all of these projects are already live on my production server, where they do not have the corresponding git repo's... yet.

What I'd like to do is be able to pull down commits from bitbucket for each corresponding project so that changes are reflected... and also sets up the git repo on the production server for that project as well.

I hope I explained that right.  I'm using SSH and I'm able to `git init`... also tried `git pull` and `git fetch` ... but then when I try to `git status` after the pull or fetch.... it shows all my files on the production server as untracked.  However, they should be already tracked as reflected on my bitbucket repo. Right?

I'm a little confused as to how to do this properly despite hours of reading.  Any help or direction pointing would be great!

Comment: Did you execute a 'git init' or a 'git clone' on your production server?  Are you pulling from a branch or from master?

Comment: I've been doing a `git init` to start it... add and commit all the files... then I do a pull from the bitbuckets repo.  Really not sure if this is the right method.  I'm getting merging conflicts whenever I make a change on my local machine, push it to bitbucket, and then try to pull down to production server.

Comment: Are you pushing code from production server to bitbucket?

Answer (score 1):

My assumptions are that you did an init on the production server.

```
git init
```

And then added bitbucket as a remote repo

```
git remote add bitbucket git://bitbucket.com/project
```

All you should be doing is committing locally, fetching and either merging or rebasing.

The commit commits your changes to your local repository and will no be reflected on bitbucket.

git commit -a -m 'committing'

The fetch pulls any changes from bitbucket down to your server.

```
git fetch bitbucket
```

The merge will merge any new changes into your repository on the server.

```
git merge bitbucket/master
```

However, I personally prefer rebase over merging in this scenario so that local changes are essentially appended to the last commit instead inter-weaved with the commits on bitbucket/master.  I find that rebasing reduces the amount of conflicts.

git rebase bitbucket/master

It is possible to get a merging conflict.  In that case, you should edit the conflicted area, execute a 'git add' on the files that were conflicted and then commit them again.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure incorrectly SSH. Look here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git
And try to do

*git remote add origin [link to yor repo]*